# Don't work alert code jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get an alert after click on submit button. I tried with the following code, but it doesn't work. How can it be done?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7atv7zgp/

```js
     $('body').delegate('.submit', 'submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
         alert('ok');
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="addres" id="keyword-txt5">
 <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   $('body').on('submit','form', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('ok');
        })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7atv7zgp/2/

**Form element have submit event**, *not button* it self. (also, i've used on() method, rather than delegate(), but you can use delegate() if you need older version of jquery).

Answer (score 0):

Simply bind the click event with the button via a class 'submit' and it will solve your purpose

```
$('.submit').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('ok');
});
```